# How to show all URIs of Provider are there in an application?

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I am using Drozer tool (refer: https://www.mwrinfosecurity.com/products/drozer/)

This tool has many utilities and one of them that allows me to list all URIs up in an application. For example:

If I execute: run scanner.provider.finduris -a com.android.contacts

```
Unable to Query  content://icc2/sdn/
Unable to Query  content://logs/call/frequent/
Unable to Query  content://com.android.contacts/raw_contacts/adn2/
Unable to Query  content://com.samsung.rcs.serviceprovider
Unable to Query  content://com.android.contacts/groups_list/aggregated/
Unable to Query  content://com.android.contacts/digit_name_lookup_full/
Unable to Query  content://logs/call/frequent
Unable to Query  content://com.android.contacts/log_name_lookup/
Unable to Query  content://icc2/adn/emails
Unable to Query  content://com.sec.provider.simcardmanagement/registerinfo/
Unable to Query  content://logs/duration
Unable to Query  content://com.samsung.rcs.rcscontacts/contacts

Accessible content URIs:
  content://com.android.settings.personalvibration.PersonalVibrationProvider/
  content://com.android.settings.personalvibration.PersonalVibrationProvider
```

My problem here is: is there any mechanism that I can do the same Drozer tool does? There ought to be a way to do it but I don't know it currently. Therefore,
With an application and its packagename, how can I list up all URIs are there in the application?

I am very looking forward to seeing your answers.

Comment: You should be able to use `PackageManager` to find the authorities (first segment after the `content://` scheme). Whatever Drozer is doing to identify paths after that is unlikely to be completely reliable.

Comment: I can find the authorities. For example, in the Contact app. I have found the authority is: com.sec.android.app.dialertab.calllog.LogsFindoSuggestionsProvider

But I'm wondering why some URIs in my post that aren't started with the authority String? Do you know how Drozer can do it? 
Beside, can you give me some examples that can list up all URIs from the authority? Anyways, I want to say thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2):

All that drozer is doing is performing a **strings** on the **classes.dex** of the package being targeted. It is then parsing out everything that starts with content://. This is a completely unreliable method and should only be used as a starting point.
Source: **findContentUris()** in https://github.com/mwrlabs/drozer/blob/develop/src/drozer/modules/common/provider.py

There is no official Android API to retrieve full content URI paths and this is why drozer had to use a hacky method. You would have the read and understand the content provider code in order to obtain all possible paths.

Comment: I could find out a solution for me. It is absolutely like yours. Anyways, I still have to say thank to you for your best answer.